# Why doesn't this code read the number correctly?

Tags: python

```
# Inport functions.
from random import randint
from random import seed
# Generate numbers. The first seed is based off of how many milliseconds have passed since Epoch (1970). Aka theres no way to perfectly predict this.
seed(randint(0,100))
x = randint(0,100)
seed(randint(0,100))
y = randint(0,100)
seed(randint(0,100))
z = randint(0,100)
seed(randint(0,100))
a = randint(0,100)
seed(randint(0,100))
b = randint(0,100)
list = [a,b,x,y,z]
# Input number.
input = int(input('Input a whole number from 0 - 100.'))
# Simple check loop. 5 times since theres 5 numbers.
for x in list:
            '# If input matches first item in list
        if input == list[0]:
            '# Set Y to 1 than stop looping.
            Y = 1
            break
        else:
            '# Otherwise delete the first item in the list and try again.
            Y = 0
            del list[0]
# Than if Y is one print bingo, otherwise print try again.
if Y == 1:
        print('Bingo!')
else:
        print('Try again.')
```

This py3 code always prints 'Try again.' I've tried forcefully setting x to 9 but it doesn't work, can anyone diagnose this? I've made sure it was properly indented in codesculpter3, anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: You code is very poorly formatted. Can you please make sure that you don't have a ' in front of your comments starting with #?

Comment: Do not name on of variable `list` as it is a built-in

Comment: you have used `input` as a variable !

Comment: also, you are deleting items from a list that you are appending...  not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few errors (see the comments). But in particular, you have used `list` and `input` as variables. The code is also **appending a list that it is iterating over**, which can lead to errors (hint: if you ever do this, then create a new list).

This is a "pythonic" version of the code that would work:

```py
import random

# random list of 5 numbers (0 to 100)
my_list = [random.randint(0,100) for x in range(5)]

got_it = 0  # variable for correct guess
for x in my_list:
    y = int(input('Input a whole number from 0 - 100.'))
    if y == x:
        got_it = 1
        print('bingo !')
        break
if got_it == 0:
    print('try again')
```